# Writing a file. Java. Android

Tags: java, android, file

```
 final String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Slots/";
    final File file = new File(rootPath);
    file.mkdirs();
    final File sdFile = new File(file, "Profile.txt");
try {
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sdFile));
    bw.write(edit.getText().toString() + "\n");
    bw.write("5000");
    } catch (IOException e) {
}
```

In this code catches IOException, but file is created. Help please! Thanks all for answers.

Comment: Well what does the exception say? What's in the file?

Comment: please explain more and try to write a more clear question with code samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 final String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Slots/";
 final File file = new File(rootPath);
 file.mkdirs();
 final File sdFile = new File(file, "Profile.txt");
try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(sdFile);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write("hello "+"\n");
        bw.write("5000");
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("exception ",e.getMessage());
    }
```

make sure you add this permission in your manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```